# Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried to run a prediction on a SegNet model, but when the predict function its call I received an error.

I tried also to run the prediction with the `with tf.device('/cpu:0'):`, but I received the same error

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # path to the model
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('segnet_weightsONNXbackToKeras3.h5')

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='RMSprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.summary()

    input_shape = [None, 360, 480, 3]
    output_shape = [None, 352, 480, 20]

    img = cv2.imread('test4.jpg')
    input_image = img
    img = cv2.resize(img, (input_shape[2], input_shape[1]))
    img = np.reshape(img, [1, input_shape[1], input_shape[2], input_shape[3]])

    if normalize:
        img = img.astype('float32') / 255

    model.summary()
    classes = model.predict(img)[0]
    colors = []
    for i in range(output_shape[3]):
        colors.append(generate_color())

    maxMatrix = np.amax(classes, axis=2)
    prediction = np.zeros((output_shape[1], output_shape[2], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

```sh
2019-10-25 19:32:03.126831: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:642] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU
     [[{{node model/LAYER_7/MaxPool}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../mold_segmentation_h5VM.py", line 62, in <module>
    classes = model.predict(img)[0]
  File "..\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 909, in predict
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "..\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU
     [[node model/LAYER_7/MaxPool (defined at D:\EB-AI\tools\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_4421]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

Comment: Nothing in this question appears connected to CUDA. I would suggest clarifying the question or removing the [cuda] tag.

Answer (score 8):

Without `test4.jpg` it's difficult to test solutions. However, the error `Default MaxPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU`
means that the model only can accept inputs of the form n_examples x height x width x channels.
I think your `cv2.resize` and subsequent `np.reshape` lines are not outputting the image in the correct format. Try printing out the shape of the image before you call model.predict(), and make sure it's in the format n_examples x height x width x channels.

Comment: You can find the image here https://ibb.co/cLLqWNG.  
The initial shape of the image is (720, 1280, 3) and after reshape operations become 
(1, 360, 480, 3).
With the original model, this script run without a problem.
The model 'segnet_weightsONNXbackToKeras3.h5' it's converted to ONNX and then back to Keras using onnx2keras library.
If you need I can send to you the Keras model.

Answer (score 1):

I had an error "AvgPoolingOp only supports NHWC on device type CPU".
In this case was useful:
`pip install intel-tensorflow` instead of regular tensorflow